# adding button to center of navigationcontroller

Tags: ios, navigationcontroller

how to add button to center of navigationcontroller i have tried the below code

> UIButton *titleButton = [UIButtonbuttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
>
> ```
> [titleButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 35)];
>
> self.navigationItem.titleView = titleButton;
> ```

but the screen shows blank button with out colour how to show it normal

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear? How exactly do you want the button to look like? No border? White background? Black text?

Answer (score 1):

```
UIButton *titleButton = [UIButtonbuttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

[titleButton setFrame:CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width - 200)/2, 3, 200, 35)];

[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:titleButton];
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this with my codes working fine

```
UIButton *titleButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[titleButton setTitle:@"Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[titleButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 35)];

self.navigationItem.titleView = titleButton;
```

try it.

Comment: still below the title of the button it is showing white colour it is not showing normal state colour

Comment: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect will always show you UIButton in white color, what you want to do with the button background??

Comment: make it look like normal button